# Vector Question Help

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis

A plane is determined by $(x,y,z) = (1,-1,0) + t(1,-1,2)$ and point $p(1,2,3)$. find point of intersection of $(1,4,-1)+s(-6,2,-4)$ with this plane.

I tried this: given the data plane equation is:$$ (x,y,z) = (1-,1,0) + t(1,-1,2)+w(1-1,2+1,3-0)= (1-,1,0) + t(1,-1,2)+w(0,3,3)$$  In Cartesian representation this is:$$  3x+y-z=2 $$ general point of the line is: $(1-6s,4+2s,-1-4s)$. we'll substitute that into $3x+y-z=2$, yielding $s=2$, hence point of intersection is $(-7,8,-9)$. this doesn't match the answers though..

Comment: Shouldn't that first "and" be a plus sign? Also, the first vector's second entry seems to be $\;-1\;$ but the minus sign is off...

Comment: those are the coordinates of a point not a vector

Comment: I get s = 1/2, not 2.

Comment: you are right man, missed there..